# python program isn't reading input and returning proper output

Tags: python

The program is meant to read a text file containing tuples that have a key (integers 1-1000), and an associated english and hmong word. It then creates a dictionary.

User then enters an english sentence and the dictionary returns the translation in hmong. If the entry contains words not in the text file, it returns a question mark.

It then asks if they want to enter another sentence, if they say no then the program will return a list that prints the frequency of each english word that the user entered during the program.

I have the general script done but the logic is just not working and I'm unsure why. When I have try to enter an english sentence the program returns `Hmong: ?` even though the words are in the text file, but when I enter the same sentence into the `Another translation (Y/N):` field, it then accepts the sentence but won't print the translation and instead just prints the frequency of the words.

```py
import string

def load_dictionary(filename):
    file=open(filename)
    word_dict=dict()
    for line in file:
        fields=line.strip().split(',')
        if len(fields)==3:
            hmong_list=fields[1].lower()
            english_list=fields[2].lower()
            word_dict[english_list]=hmong_list
        file.close()
    return word_dict
def translate(sentence):
    list_words=load_dictionary('C:\\Users\\Bridget\\Downloads\\HmongWords.txt')
    translated=''
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in list_words:
            translated+=list_words[word]+' '
        else:
            translated+='? '
    return translated.strip()
def print_word_frequency(text):
    freq_words=dict()
    for word in text.split():
        if word in freq_words:
            freq_words[word]+=1
        else:
            freq_words[word]=1
        print('{:10s} {:10s}'.format('Word', 'Frequency'))
    for word in freq_words:
        print('{:10s} {:10d}'.format(word,freq_words[word]))
def main():
    flag=True
    converted_text=''
    while flag:
        sentence=input("Type your English sentence: ")
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        for i in string.punctuation:
            sentence = sentence.replace(i,' ')
        translated=translate(sentence)
        print('Hmong: ',translated)
        converted_text+=sentence+' '
        flag=input("Another translation (Y/N): ").lower()=='y'
    print_word_frequency(converted_text)
main()
```

Sample run

```
Type your English sentence: I can help you help him.
Hmong:  ?
Another translation (Y/N): Y
Type your English sentence: I can help you help him
Hmong:  ?
Another translation (Y/N): I can help you help him
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
Word       Frequency 
i                   2
can                 2
help                4
you                 2
him                 2
```

I also am not seeing why it prints word and frequency over and over instead of just once. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of your `word_dict` to check it contains what you think?  For example (unless it's just a problem with the formatting of the code you pasted), it appears that the `return` statement in the `load_dictionary` function is inside the `for` loop: this would result in only the first line of the file being processed.

Comment: The same thing is true in `translate`.  You really need to pay more attention to indentation.

Comment: your indentation needs some work. it may be due to formatting, but in your first `for line in file` loop, you close the file inside the loop instead of outside. This will cause the code to only read the first line of the file.

Comment: @slothrop oh my gosh you are totally right! I completely missed that! I changed that but it now returns "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" for line 6, 15, 41, 46. I can delete "file.close()" from the load_dictionary function but I thought it was required to close a file?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I thought they were meant to be indented to the same as the loops but I understand that isn't correct now, thank you!

Comment: @blankettripod yeah I am a bit confused by that! I am getting a value error now saying the file is closed so should I just take that out completely or are you saying it's just an indent issue?

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer that will show why your code is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains 2 problems.

First. You are not reading from the file correctly. `for line in file` is not the correct way, you need to do `for line in file.readlines()`

Second. You close the file after the first iteration of the loop

```py
for line in file:
    fields=line.strip().split(',')
    if len(fields)==3:
        hmong_list=fields[1].lower()
        english_list=fields[2].lower()
        word_dict[english_list]=hmong_list
    file.close() # here
```

the `file.close()` should be indented one less

```py
for line in file:
    fields=line.strip().split(',')
    if len(fields)==3:
        hmong_list=fields[1].lower()
        english_list=fields[2].lower()
        word_dict[english_list]=hmong_list
file.close() # should be here
```

Comment: You are incredible thank you! I can't believe it was something so simple. Is an indent issue the same reason that word and frequency keep printing over and over when the user ends the session?

Comment: No, that is because your sentence is getting replaced with empty words, which then have empty counts, once you fix the translation, that part will work aswell

Comment: turns out it was both! Had to fix one indent and applied your tweaks and it's finally working! Thank you so so much!!

Comment: if the answer works for you, please accept and upvote : )